# Depth-first search

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, suffix-tree

I have a suffix tree, each node of this tree is a struct

```
struct state {
int len, link;
map<char,int> next; };
state[100000] st;
```

I need to make dfs for each node and get all strings which I can reach, but I don't know how to make.
This is my dfs function

```
 void getNext(int node){
  for(map<char,int>::iterator it = st[node].next.begin();it != st[node].next.end();it++){
      getNext(it->second);
 }
}
```

It will be perfect if I can make something like

```
map<int,vector<string> >
```

where int is a node of my tree and vector strings which I can reach

now it works

```
void createSuffices(int node){//, map<int, vector<string> > &suffices) {
if (suffices[sz - 1].size() == 0 && (node == sz - 1)) {
    // node is a leaf
    // add a vector for this node containing just 
    // one element: the empty string
    //suffices[node] = new vector<string>
    //suffices.add(node, new vector<string>({""}));
    vector<string> r;
    r.push_back(string());
    suffices[node] = r;
} else {
    // node is not a leaf
    // create the vector that will be built up
    vector<string> v;
    // loop over each child
    for(map<char,int>::iterator it = st[node].next.begin();it != st[node].next.end();it++){
        createSuffices(it->second);
        vector<string> t = suffices[it->second];
        for(int i = 0; i < t.size(); i ++){
            v.push_back(string(1,it->first) + t[i]);
        }
    }
    suffices[node] = v;
}
}
```

Comment: Why use a map, you want this for each node so just make a vector of vector<string> pointers. Either way, you will have quite a lot of redundancy.

Comment: I think the check for a leaf is wrong. A node is a leaf if it has no children, that is, if `next` is an empty map. I don't know what `sz` is in the snippet above, but it seems incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `map<int, vector<string>>` together with your depth first search. When a recursive call returns from a certain node `n`, you know that all suffices from that node are ready. My C++ skills are too limited, so I'll write it in pseudo-code:

```
void createSuffices(int node, map<int, vector<string>> suffices) {
    if (st[node].next.empty()) {
        // node is a leaf
        // add a vector for this node containing just 
        // one element: the empty string
        suffices.add(node, new vector<string>({""}));
    } else {
        // node is not a leaf
        // create the vector that will be built up
        vector<string> v;
        // loop over each child
        foreach pair<char, int> p in st[node].next {
            // handle the child
            createSuffices(p.second, suffices);

            // prepend the character to all suffices of the child
            foreach string suffix in suffices(p.second) {
                v.add(concatenate(p.first, suffix));
            }                
        }
        // add the created vector to the suffix map
        suffices.add(node, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: as i can see there is some problems, suffices are empry every time

Comment: Do we need by ref rather than by val if we want to change suffices: `map<int, vector<string>> & suffices`

Comment: @doctorlove yes, absolutely. I tried to write it down C++ish (with references), but I got stuck, so I decided to write it as simple as I could... but indeed, the map *must* be passed by reference or this won't work.

Comment: @Heuster i make it global